# Bootbox: Make the default button work with the ENTER key?

Tags: javascript, html, bootbox

As the title suggests, I want to add the Enter key as an event handler for Bootbox.js. When you an alert() popup is called, you can press enter to dismiss it, but that is not the case with Bootbox.js. I do not know how to get access to the button inside Bootbox.js to add an event handler. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order for the button to take focus, it should be defined with the "btn-primary" class name:

```
className:
main: {
      className: "btn-primary",  ...
}
```

Comment: this is only working when we do not have focus on any input field.

Answer (score 6):

I see this post has no answer yet for case when user has focus in the form itself

Here's how to do it :

**Code :**

```
$(document).on("submit", ".bootbox form", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".bootbox .btn-primary").click();
});

bootbox.dialog({
    title : "Title",
    message : $("#templateWithForm").html(),
    onEscape : true,
    buttons : 
    {
        success : {
            label : "OK",
            className : "btn-success btn-primary",
            callback : function() {
                // do something...
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Explanation :**

First bit of code will catch the "submit" event for all bootbox dialogs with forms in it and prevent the submit with `preventDefault()` it will then emulate a click on the button that has `className : "btn-primary"`

(Note that it's going to trigger a click to all bootbox dialogs so you might wanna change it for your use case if you have more than a dialog on the page at once)

Second bit of code is a simple dialog calling. Important parts are

- `onEscape : true` if you want to close the dialog with Escape key
- `className : "btn-success btn-primary"` btn-success can obviously be changed to fit your needs

Hope this helps the next person !

Comment: All these years later, working on a legacy project and this was the answer I needed. It feels like a "hack" when it should be built-in functionality, but it works.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add 'bootbox-accept' className for the button you want to click on enter key press.

Example:

```
bootbox.dialog({
    title : "Title",
    message : "Your Message",
    onEscape : true,
    buttons : 
    {
        success : {
            label : "OK",
            className : "btn-success bootbox-accept",
            callback : function() {
                // do something...
            }
        },
        cancel:{
            label : "Cancel",
            className : "btn-danger",
            callback : function() {
                // do something...
            }
        },
    }
})
```

Comment: nice! its really works for me! thank u Pearl!

Answer (score -1):

use btnclassName and assign "btn-primary as below in code

function ShowpopUp() {

```
    bootbox.confirm({
        size: "Large",
        btnclassName: "btn-primary",
         title: "Guests from outside your organization",
        message: "The following recipients are from outside of the SPSG organization:<br> <br> "
            +
            getSelectedNonMembersEmails()

            + "<br> <br> Are you sure you would like to send it?",

        callback: function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                reportVm.currentPage(4);
            }
            else {
                bootbox.hideAll();

            }
        }
    });
}
```